# Cannot find my WordPress admin URL

Tags: wordpress

Took over a job from a previous person, and he didn't leave the WordPress login URL. Have no idea what it is. Is there a way I can find this URL? Have login information, just no URL.

Comment: It's typically just `/wp-admin` on your installed domain.

Comment: have you tried this?  http://example.com/wp-login.php  

example.com will be your domain.

Comment: Yea. I've tried wp-login, wp-admin, with and without .php, admin, siteadmin, /wp-admin/login.php

Comment: Do you have FTP access? Have you tried to login via FTP?

Comment: If you can share the live website url, maybe we can help to find it.

Comment: I got the FTP login, and have access, but it doesn't look like a WordPress managed site now that I look at it. I'm just trying to find the contact form and change around the email for the sales team. The form looks done in java, can't find the mailto anywhere.     The URL is http://www.metrotowntoolrental.ca.

Comment: Nope. It is WordPress. I have found plugins, but it's gotta be an old version.

Comment: My first thought was to get a site map, but I tested that on my site and it does not retrieve the login. Perhaps you could try this: http://www.seoadministrator.com/site-analyzer.html ... There's a free trial. Hopefully it's worth something. GL!

Comment: Thanks! I actually have Xenu, and maybe that would do the same sort of thing? Your hoping it'll grab the login page, right? Also, if you look at this contact form, can you tell what the file the php or html post email will be located in? http://www.metrotowntoolrental.ca/contact. I can't tell by looking at it.

Comment: @SereneTheif looking at the source code, that doesn't not look like a wordpress site at all.

Comment: @scdr Yea I thought that was the case when I checked out the FTP. So I'll just have to look for the form manually in the FTP.

Comment: No, Xeno does not seem the same to me. Both check for broken links, but that is useless in this senario. I never tried the SEO administrator, but it claims to come with a site analyzer

"In this case the file exists on the website but there are no links to it. Our site analyzer will, optionally, scan the FTP catalog of the site and compare it with the list of (http) scanned html pages from the site analysis. Lost files will show up as differences between the two lists and can readily be identified."

It may not do a better job than a sitemap creator though... Up to you to find out I guess :)